# how to read xml files in python if the encoding is different than UTF-8

Tags: python, file-handling

I am trying to read an xml file with different encoding. In case of `UTF-8` it is working fine but in case of other formats like `GB18030` or `BIG5`, it is throwing error like multi-byte encoding are not supported.

Please suggest a solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here a try is open as file object and with `ElementTree.fromstring()` :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

with open('file_name.xml','r') as f:
   ef = ET.fromstring(f.read())
```

It was worked for me.

Or you can do is with `XMLParser` :

```
xmlp = ET.XMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
f = ET.parse('file_name.xml',parser=xmlp)
```